# file not found exception even there is a image in that location

Tags: java, filenotfoundexception

i am reading a image from a server using **java (spring mvc)** following code

```
if(imagePath != null && imagePath.length() > 0 )
            {       

                byte fileContent[] = new byte[3000];
                try (FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(new File(imagePath))) {// here is the Exception
                    while(fin.read(fileContent) >= 0) {
                        // Base64.encodeBase64(fileContent);
                    }
                } 
}
```

**path**

```
/var/sentora/hostdata/campusguru/public_html/resources/images/bharath.png
```

there is image in that location but im getting following exception

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: \var\sentora\hostdata\campusguru\public_html\resources\images\bharath.png (The system cannot find the path specified)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.rasvek.cms.controller.StudentController.getStudentAdmissionByAdmissionId(StudentController.java:696)
at com.rasvek.cms.controller.StudentController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$cb2af793.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:738)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.invoke(MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.java:52)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.invoke(AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.java:52)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673)
at com.rasvek.cms.controller.StudentController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$bbc517cf.getStudentAdmissionByAdmissionId(<generated>)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1100)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:687)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

if the path is on windows i am getting any exception (in local system )

but on the network server which is **linux**  i am geeting file not found exception.

please help me ,thank you .

Comment: The path separator is /, not \ on Linux.

Comment: The exception's text shows you're using `\`s, not `/`s.

Comment: Use `File.separator` instead of hard coded  path separator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using hardcoded path aren't you? Linux path separator is `/` and on windows it is `\`. Generate path to files dynamically and also prefer `File.exists()` check rather then running into exception.

Comment: yes i am getting path from db and trying to get file from that location. i am confused can you please give me example for it.

Comment: You can save your configurations in yaml and read them as per environment. Save the parent directory in yaml and image name in db and when you need path, combine two using File.seperator

Comment: what is  `yaml` ?

Comment: YAML is a human-readable data serialization language. Configuration values like the one which changes depending upon environment are stored in YAML file. Google it, it's very useful technique. Don't put your credentials in it.

Answer (score 0):

Its not clear that you are getting file from a server or local!

**In the first scenario :** If you are getting file from server then you can't use direct path on the server!
In this case: /var/sentora/hostdata/campusguru/public_html/resources/images/bharath.png
you can use ftp or such file sharing or you can use SAMBA

https://askubuntu.com/questions/15782/how-do-i-share-a-folder-with-another-linux-machine-on-the-same-home-network

**In the second scenario :** If you are getting files from local mounted drive, you must have read access to this file by using "chmod +r" command to add read privilege to the Linux user that you are running app server or application with.

In this case you must using full path and its better to use relative path related to resource path in your Spring MVC project.